# grub rescue unknown filesystem

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub, arch-linux, bootable-media

i am dual booting Win11 and artix linux(or trying to do so..)

i have celan installed win 11, shrunk volume of drive, and w rufus created USB to install artix with

after restart n selecting USB i just fall into grub rescue

i can ls the drives

in my case (hd0) (hd1)

however i cant further ls neither drive

ls (hd0)/

just returns unknown filesystem, so i cant even get to the step of finding the /boot/grub path or whatever and set perfix, set root n insmod basically as the answer in this thread says - https://askubuntu.com/questions/142300/how-to-fix-error-unknown-filesystem-grub-rescue

so what do i do now, its as if the live iso is damaged or idk whats going on

Answer (score 0):

Artix is similar to Arch, so this excerpt from the wiki might be useful:

> If the USB drive does not boot properly using the default ISO Image mode, DD Image mode should be used instead. To switch this mode on, select GPT from the Partition scheme drop-down menu. After clicking START you will get the mode selection dialog, select DD Image mode.